# How to fix this error django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address . Docker

Tags: django, docker, operationalerror

I am using Pyscopg.
**DOCKER-COMPOSE:**

```
 version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db2
  db2:
    image: postgres:11
```

**SETTINGS.PY:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db2',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

Getting this
**Error:** django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db2" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Answer (score 2):

It works, when you add

`environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres`

to docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Searched for hours `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`...it was `POSTGRES_PASSOWRD` :-/ beware of typos!

Comment: I got the same problem, please where and which position should add the above line of codes, I had tried many methods, but it just did not work for me.